# AngualrJS 1.3 manually update binding with one time binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use one-time binding in my view {{::vm.list}}.  That's all working well and good.  However on a button click I want vm.list to refresh.

I can't seem to figure out how to manually trigger vm.list to update.  Perhaps one time binding is not the answer?

here is a jsfiddle boilerplate example: http://jsfiddle.net/KamelJabber/e4nexvay/2/

```js
(function () {
    var c1 = function Controller1() {
        var vm = this;
        var addCount = 1;
        vm.list = [{
            Id: 1,
            Text: "Blue One"
        }, {
            Id: 2,
            Text: "Blue Two"
        }, {
            Id: 3,
            Text: "Blue Three"
        }];

        vm.AddnRefresh = function () {
            vm.list.push({
                Id: vm.list.length,
                Text: "Add " + addCount
            });
            addCount++;

            //force a refresh of vm.list
        }
    };

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('Controller1', c1);
})();
```

```css
<style> </style> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Controller1 as vm">
        <p>
            <input type="button" ng-click="vm.AddnRefresh();" value="Add" />
        </p>
        <div ng-repeat="l in ::vm.list">{{::l.Text}}</div>
        <p></p>
        <div>LOTS of other stuff going on causing digest updates so really don't want to update list unless "Add" is called"</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: added a working answer

Comment: OK, the following works but not sure if it's a good idea: http://jsfiddle.net/KamelJabber/e4nexvay/3/  The first time the page loads vm.getList() is called twice.  It is never initiated on digest updates unless manually triggered in vm.AddnRefresh().

Comment: oops, the above actually did not work :(  sorry

Comment: the problem is you want to do it one-way but, you want to change the list. But in one-way you cant change it. One way is just to view it. And if you remove the :: it will called twice too. It is really hard to handle the cycles..

Answer (score 5):

I'm late to the party but I'll pitch in nevertheless.

I've been working on a notifier module for some time now and it's finally reached a 1.0.0 state where I feel I can start recommending it.

[angular-bind-notifier](https://github.com/kasperlewau/angular-bind-notifier/)

You could use this in two ways;

1. Setup a watcher for a single property to update multiple bindings.
2. `$broadcast` events manually to refresh a one-time binding.

---

I reckon #2 would be the best way to fulfill what you're looking for and that would go something like this:

```
<input type="button" ng-click="vm.AddnRefresh();" value="Add" />

<div ng-repeat="l in :refresh:vm.list">
  {{::l.Text}}
</div>
```

Notice the `refresh` that's been added between your one-time colons. This is the `key` you will utilise when wanting to trigger a refresh of the data.

All you need to do now is to update the `AddnRefresh` method like so:

```
vm.addnRefresh = function () {
  /** original implementation **/
  $scope.$broadcast('$$rebind::refresh'); // where 'refresh' is the key used in the view. 
};
```

*`$$rebind::` is the internal event namespace used by angular-bind-notifier.*

And there you go - your view is now updated.

---

Here's a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/xaxazulavu/1/edit?html,js,output) showcasing both ways of updating (1 $watcher & manual $broadcast).

Comment: this looks awesome and exactly what I was looking to do!  I'll try to pull together some time to try it out!

Comment: Cool :) if it doesn't work and/or you think you've found a bug - please post an issue on GitHub!

Answer (score 3):

Angular will re-render the view if the parent DOM element is re-created.
You can use a combination of ng-if, scope variable and $timeout service to achieve this:

**View:**

```
<div ng-if="!vm.status.reqRefresh">
     <div ng-repeat="l in ::vm.list">{{::l.Text}}</div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
vm.status = {
    reqRefresh : false
};

vm.AddnRefresh = function () {
    vm.list.push({
        Id : vm.list.length,
        Text : "Add " + addCount
    });
    addCount++;

    //force a refresh of vm.list
    vm.status.reqRefresh = true;
    $timeout(function () {
        vm.status.reqRefresh = false;
    });
}
```

See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/karank007/e4nexvay/143/

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution, i'm going to to try it out!

Comment: Nice one, works very well for me too, and a simple solution.

Answer (score -1):

Hay you have to use the `$scope` to see the updated view. I've just added the `vm` in to a Scope. Here is the code:

```
  (function () {
    var c1 = function Controller1($scope) {
       $scope.vm = this;
        var addCount = 1;
        $scope.vm.list = [{
            Id: 1,
            Text: "Blue One"
        }, {
            Id: 2,
            Text: "Blue Two"
        }, {
            Id: 3,
            Text: "Blue Three"
        }];

       $scope.vm.AddnRefresh = function () {
            $scope.vm.list.push({
                Id: $scope.vm.list.length,
                Text: "Add " + addCount
            });
            addCount++;

            //force a refresh of vm.list
        }

    };

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('Controller1', c1);
})();
```

You also have to remove the `::`:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="Controller1 as vm">
        <p>
            <input type="button" ng-click="vm.AddnRefresh();" value="Add" />
        </p>
        <div ng-repeat="l in vm.list">{{::l.Text}}</div>
        <p></p>
        <div>LOTS of other stuff going on causing digest updates so really don't want to update list unless "Add" is called"</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey thanks!  your example would work, however, not quite what I'm after.  I actually do not want "list" to update on digest updates.  I do want it to update when manually click "Add" though.  Note, there are number of other digest updates occurring on the page.  When those occur I do not want list to trigger an update.  Moreover, list is being populated in a separate process so I also want those updates to hold off until "Add" is pushed.  Maybe this is better? <div ng-repeat="l in getList()"><div>?